# Excel VBA: When I click the + beside a group of rows

Tags: excel, vba

When I click the + beside a group of rows, how do I get it to hide a row outside of the grouped rows.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Target.Rows(11).Hidden = True) Then
    Rows(22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows(22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply hiding or un-hiding a row will not trigger the Event, To use this Event, you must change a cell value.

**EDIT#1**

You can **almost** get what you want with the *Worksheet_SelectionChange* event.

Expand or collapse the Group of rows containing cell **A11** and then click anywhere in the worksheet and row #22 will also expand/collapse.  Put the following in a standard module:

```
Public Sub IsHiddenA11()
   With Range("A11")
   If .EntireRow.Hidden Then
      Range("A22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Else
      Range("A22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
   End If
   End With
End Sub
```

and put this in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call IsHiddenA11
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, how can I trigger the event by clicking the + beside the Grouped rows

Comment: I don't know...... *Group/Ungroup* does not change *Selection*  It does not even "hide" the rows since *SubTotal()* does not change either.