# Excel Determine if user hides/unhides columns

Tags: excel, vba

I've got worksheets that users will be hiding/unhiding columns on for printing purposes. Within those columns are certain cells which need to be copied to a visible area when those columns are hidden and the process reversed when they are not. The function works fine to detect the columns' visible status when the worksheet is activated. However it does not update at the time the column statuses are changed. I understand that the worksheet_calculate sub will detect changes in row visibility, but not columns, nor does it work in worksheet_change. Worksheet_SelectionChange seems buggy (selects more than selected even without code). Suggestions?

```
Public Function Copy_Hidden_ChargeCode_Descriptions(ByRef sht As String)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Worksheets(sht).Columns("C:G").Hidden = False Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets(sht).Range("H4")) Then
            Worksheets(sht).Range("H1").Cut Worksheets(sht).Range("C1")
            Worksheets(sht).Range("H4:N9").Cut Worksheets(sht).Range("C4:H9")
        End If
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets(sht).Range("H4")) Then
            Worksheets(sht).Range("C1").Cut Worksheets(sht).Range("H1")
            Worksheets(sht).Range("C4:H9").Cut Worksheets(sht).Range("H4:N9")
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: The code works.

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Grouped the columns and then called the function from worksheet_selectionchange. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370883/excel-vba-when-i-click-the-beside-a-group-of-rows